# Changing scaffold-controller-generator-templates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding, scaffold

When I use the Rails scaffold generator to create my Rails-files, it creates among others a controller file. e.g.

`rails generate scaffold potato`

generates:

`app/controllers/potatos_controller.rb`

For my project I want this file a little more specific. E.g. I want to change this automatic generated action:

```
def create
  @potato = Potato.new(potato_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @potato.save
      format.html { redirect_to @potato, notice: 'Potato was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @potato }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @potato.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

to use a I18n-translation instead of the hardcoded *'Potato was successfully created.'* Also I want to change some indentations, since rubocop is always complaining about it.

I have found the template of the scaffold-generator and now want to make my changes. For this I have created a file in my project:
`lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb`
In this file I have made my changes. (e.g. I changed the line

```
redirect_to @<%= singular_table_name %>, notice: <%= "'#{human_name} was successfully created.'" %>
```

to

```
redirect_to @<%= singular_table_name %>, notice: <%= "'#{human_name} THIS IS A TEST.'" %>
```

But unfortunately the changes don't work. The scaffold generator still uses its own template. So what am I doing wrong here? Am I missing a step?

**Update:**
Here is the output of the generate-command:

```
rails generate scaffold potato      

Running via Spring preloader in process 31479
  invoke  active_record
  ...

  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/potatos_controller.rb
  ...
```

**Screenshot of the railties:**

[image: Railtiesenter image description here]

Comment: who you solve your problem? I try withMihai answer but to not works.

Comment: Hey, I am having the same issues, I feel like the code there is not the same as what is being generated. Did you ever find where the code is being generated?

Comment: No, I decided I don't care

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails 4 shows you which template is using

```
rails generate scaffold potato
...
invoke  scaffold_controller
```

You should host your modified templates in your project, i.e.
`lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb`.

Please note that the Responders gem might change the generator used to
`lib/templates/rails/responders_controller/controller.rb`.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I checked the output of the generator and it sais, that it invokes `scaffold_controller` - the one that i was trying to edit. (See updated question)

Comment: That's interesting. Can you try editting `responders_controller` too and see what happens?

Comment: I have also added a screenshot if the directory structure of my rails-generators. It seems there is no *responders_controller*. I tried to create the file in my project, but it didn't have any effect on the outcome.

Comment: My bad, `responders_controller` is defined by the Responders gem (used by Devise). You should put the modified templates in your project, i.e. `lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb`.

Comment: Also try without `spring`. It might not load your templates without a restart.

Comment: Of course I'll change the files in my own project and not in the railties-gem itself. ;) Unfortunately stopping spring didn't help, too.

Comment: Maybe there's a gem overwriting your template. You should debug `templates` found in `config.app_generators`. That variable holds all the paths that are checked for templates.

Answer (score 10):

If anyone finds it useful, you can copy the default railties controller scaffold templates to your own project by running this command in your project directory:

```
mkdir -p lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller && \
  cp $(bundle info railties --path)/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/* \
  lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller
```

If you use Rails 5.2 and jbuilder, you should use the `jbuilder` scaffolders as a base instead:

```
mkdir -p lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller && \
  cp $(bundle info jbuilder --path)/lib/generators/rails/templates/* \
  lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller
```

Comment: When I use this method, it overrides the template as expected. However, the generated code is not the same as without the override. I appears to be the wrong template. The original code:

Comment: When I use this method, it overrides the template as expected. However, the generated code is different. The original generated code is for both json and html formatted responses. The copied template only generates code for html responses.

Comment: I will update this soon - the JSON and HTML controller templates are in the `jbuilder` gem.

Answer (score 1):

use `rake app:templates:copy` to generate scaffold_controller.
but, It also generate helper, controller, mailer views, controller view, helper and scaffold_controller view.

on rails github, this command located in [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/tasks/framework.rake) and it also available for not just rails 7, but rails 6, rails 5 and rails 4

Answer (score 0):

The template to copy is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt) and you have to place it in `lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/` as per Tim's answer.