# Override controller test scaffold for rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, controller, generator, scaffold

I tried to override the controller test generator for scaffolding in rails 5.
I found the original file, but can't place it in the template directory.

If I read correctly this post [Changing scaffold-controller-generator-templates in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337732/changing-scaffold-controller-generator-templates-in-rails), the path should be :

```
lib/templates/rails/test_unit/controller.rb
```

or

```
lib/templates/rails/test_unit/functional_test.rb # from the scaffold sources
```

Finally I tested lots of combinaisons of directories and files names, but none work.

Does anybody know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this path? I found it by chance :)

`lib/templates/test_unit/scaffold/functional_test.rb`

Maybe following directories are also available for minitest templates

`./test_unit
./test_unit/controller
./test_unit/helper
./test_unit/integration
./test_unit/mailer
./test_unit/model
./test_unit/plugin
./test_unit/scaffold`